# How to download file in new page in php

Tags: php, html, web

i am a beginner in php and i am trying to develop a music site where users can download the songs. Now, when a user clicks the download button i want to make the song to download in new a webpage. The following is the code and i cant figureout where to modify it so that song will be downlaoded in a new webpage. Please help me to solve the problem.

```
<div class="search-buttons" >
        <!-- ON DESKTOP -->

        <a class="no-tablet-portrait no-phone button success" onclick="open_download('<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>download.php?download=<? echo $search->id; ?>', '<? echo download_mode;  ?>');" title="<? echo lng_btn_download; ?>" ><i class="icon-box-add" ></i><? echo lng_btn_download; ?></a>
        <!-- ON PHONE OR TABLET -->

       <a class="no-desktop button success" onclick="open_download('<? echo $GLOBALS["sys"]->get_url(); ?>download.php?download=<? echo $search->id; ?>', 'direct');" title="<? echo lng_btn_download; ?>" ><i class="icon-box-add" ></i>  </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Consider formatting your code better, please. Besides, it's really **huge**!

Comment: ok i will reduce it now

Comment: Edited please check it now

Comment: What does "download in new a webpage" mean? Usually you want a browser to either *download something* or *render a page*.

Comment: i want to browser to download in new blank page

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to decipher,  so I'm not going to reference it...but, here's the PHP command you need to redirect the browser to a new page

```
header('location:  [yournewpageurl here]');
```

Keep in mind that you MUST call the header command prior to generating any output (echo, print, etc) within the PHP script!

Comment: Hello DavidRothbauer, Now i had simplified the code, please consider helping me.

Comment: There's still not a lot to see there.

Comment: Hit send too soon.
You're project sounds pretty complex,  and your methods are not best practice.
You should be using javascript/jquery event handlers,  and calling your PHP scripts from there.
That's not something I can teach you in an answer here.
You'll have to do some research and play around (just like I learned).
This might help with some stuff...but it isn't meant for beginners...
http://codeismydrug.wordpress.com

This is another good site http://www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple link as this one

```
<a href=<?php //blablabla ?> target=_blank>Download!</a>
```